# Javascripts : Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxtjs

I coding this code in script tag on nuxtjs but it error.

```
<script>
    export default {
        computed: {
            user() {
                let user = [{name_en: 'Jack'},{name_en: 'Joe'}]
                return user.filter(item => item.name_en.toLowerCase().includes(keywordSearch))
            }
         }
     }
</script>
```

It error that **Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined in javascript**. But I try

```
return user.filter(item => item.name_en === 'Jack')
```

It doesn't error. I'm so confuse. How to solve this problem.

Comment: It means `name_en` is undefined for one or more items inside `user`. Simply try to  log it and find it out..

Comment: i have tested it and it works, is this the full code?

Comment: @sazzad There is [String.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) also

Comment: You are confused because if `item.name_en` is undefined it won't throw error doing an equality check that evaluates as `undefined === 'Jack'` but `undefined.toLowercase()` will throw error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try below function to 1st check if it exists and then convert that to lowercase
`user.filter(item => item.name_en && item.name_en.toLowerCase().includes(keywordSearch))`